# How to check of exceptions in nested functions when using MagicMock objects in Pytest?

Tags: python, testing, pytest, return-value, magicmock

I've a function (`myfunc`), with a validation input `a` and and `c` credentials that will setup a service to call `func_z`.

For some validation input, `func_z` will throw an error, and in other cases, it'll return some dictionary of values. And I've an `outer_func` that modifies the output of `func_z`.

I've tried to mock the `func_z` as such:

```
class XError(Excception):
    pass

def myfunc(a, b, c):
    x = c.setup_client('x')
    try:
        x.func_z(a) # Check if x.func_z(a) works proper
    except:
        raise XError
    
    return b**2


def outer_func(a, b, c):
    return myfunc(a, b, c) + 1
```

When testing the function, I had to mock the `c` credentials. So I tried to test with:

```
import pytest
from unittest.mock import MagicMock


test_data = ( (('fr', 5), 26), ('de', 7, 50), (('zh', 5), XError) )

SIDE_EFFECTS = {'fr': {'status': 'okay'}, 'de': {'status': 'okay'}, 'zh': XError}

@pytest.mark.parametrize("a, b", test_data)
def mytest(a, b, expected):
    mock_creds = MagicMock()
    mock_service = MagicMock()
    mock_creds.setup_client.return_value = mock_service
    mock_service.func_z.return_value = SIDE_EFFECTS[a]
    
    assert outer_func(a, b, mock_creds) == expected
```

Somehow the `XError` didn't get raised in the pytest and the output returns `26` for `('zh', 5)` inputs instead of XError.

But it seems like I'm not mocking anything.

**Did I use the return value in the mock objects wrongly?**

**Is it possible to allow and check for raised error or outputs with mock objects in pytest?**

Comment: In your example code, you don't mock anything, you just create mocks without connecting them to real objects - probably forgot to add some code. Can you show us an actual reproducible example?

Comment: I think that's my question too, I suspect it's not mocking anything but what I want to mock is the returns of the `func_z` according to the `SIDE_EFFECTS`

Comment: `assert outer_func(a, b, mock_creds) == expected`?

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues with the test in question.

1. Returning an exception in mock:

   ```
   mock_service.func_z.return_value = XError
   ```

   is effectively a

   ```
   def func_z():
       return XError
   ```

   Surely this is not what you want. Instead, you want `func_z` mock to *raise* an error; for that, you need to use `side_effect`:

   ```
   mock_service.func_z.side_effect = XError
   ```
2. Asserting an exception is returned from tested function: the `outer_func` doesn't *return* an exception, but raises it, so

   ```
   assert outer_func(a, b, mock_creds) == expected
   ```

   will fail for `(('zh', 5), XError)` parameter as `outer_func` will not return.

Instead, write two separate tests since you have two different paths the code can take in `myfunc`; the `test_happy` covers the path with no exception and the path with error raising is covered by `test_xerror`. The code common to both tests (assembling the `mock_service`) is moved out to a fixture.

```
@pytest.fixture
def mock_creds():
    mock_creds = MagicMock()
    mock_service = MagicMock()
    mock_creds.setup_client.return_value = mock_service
    return mock_creds


happy_data = (('fr', 5, 26), ('de', 7, 50))
SIDE_EFFECTS = {'fr': {'status': 'okay'}, 'de': {'status': 'okay'}}

@pytest.mark.parametrize("a, b, expected", happy_data)
def test_happy(mock_creds, a, b, expected):
    func_z_return = SIDE_EFFECTS[a]
    mock_creds.setup_client.return_value.func_z.return_value = func_z_return
    assert outer_func(a, b, mock_creds) == expected


xerror_data = (('zh', 5), )

@pytest.mark.parametrize("a, b", xerror_data)
def test_xerror(mock_creds, a, b):
    mock_creds.setup_client.return_value.func_z.side_effect = XError
    with pytest.raises(XError):
        outer_func(a, b, mock_creds)
```

Notice how `pytest.raises` context is used for testing whether `XError` is raised in the last test. If you want to test exception details, you can store the raised exception and inspect it after the `with` block:

```
with pytest.raises(XError) as excinfo:
    outer_func(a, b, mock_creds)
ex = excinfo.value
assert isinstance(ex, XError)  # well, duh
assert ex.message == "An XError message if passed"  # etc.
```

Comment: Good answer as usual, hoefling! Humbly mentioning, in the final example, my plugin [pytest-raisin](https://github.com/wimglenn/pytest-raisin) allows to use an instance to assert the exc type + message together `with pytest.raises(XError("An XError message if passed")):`

Comment: Thanks @wim! This is indeed an interesting addition to `pytest`; I think I can benefit from it myself, as I need to assert a lot of `pydantic.ValidationError`s in one project at work...